# How to configure phpfreechat to a private message mode?

Tags: php, html, chat, phpfreechat

This is a question for those who are or have been acquainted with phpfreechat. I have a site with a phpfreechat module. The version of phpfreechat is 2.1.0. By default, phpfreechat has a chatroom where admin and users can talk to each other. But I, as an admin, want to have private conversations with each user. I mean, I don't want to users can talk to each other, just to me.

So, the question would be: How can I do this? How can I configure phpfreechat v2.x to a private message/conversation mode? Is this posible?

Last, I want to say that I did made a properly research on Google, S.O. and phpfreechat website before asking here. Of course, without any success.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

Okay ... Not used this before, but I've had a quick look through the code, and found the function that 'sends' the message to all other users (found in /server/container/messages.php)

This function is postMsgToChannel() ...

So basically, you could try copy/modify it to create one that only sends to a single user, which may look something like this:

```
static public function postMsgToUser($cid, $ruid, $suid, $body, $type = 'msg') {

    $mid = self::generateMid($cid);
    $msg = array(
      'id'        => $mid,
      'sender'    => $suid,
      'recipient' => 'channel|'.$cid,
      'type'      => $type,
      'body'      => $body,
      'timestamp' => time(),
    );
    // json encode msg before storing
    $msg = json_encode($msg);

    //send message to single user
    $umdir = Container_users::getDir().'/'.$ruid.'/messages';
    file_put_contents($umdir.'/'.$mid, $msg);

    return $msg;

}
```

Where `$ruid` is the recipient's uid, and `$suid` is the senders uid.

The only problem I can foresee, is trying to figure out the user's id that you are sending to.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try what you're saying.